# How do I check for a duplicated text name and replace it with a new value if found using vbscript?

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, append, text-files, overwrite

```
    Set myFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("savedhosts.txt", ForReading, True)
    Set myTemp = objFSO.OpenTextFile("savedhosts.txt" & ".tmp", ForWriting, True)
    Do Until myFile.AtEndofStream
        myLine = myFile.ReadLine
        'msgbox "hostname = " & hostname
        If InStr(myLine, hostname) Then
            MsgBox "found hostname = " & hostname & " in the savedhosts.txt file"
            myLine = hostname & ";" & hostname_IP_value
            myTemp.WriteLine myLine
            myFile.Close
            myTemp.Close
            objFSO.DeleteFile("savedhosts.txt")
            objFSO.MoveFile "savedhosts.txt" & ".tmp", "savedhosts.txt" 
        Exit Sub

        Else
            Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("savedhosts.txt", ForAppending, True)
            'MsgBox "hostname & ; & hostname_IP_value = " & hostname & ";" & hostname_IP_value
            objTextFile.WriteLine(hostname_value & ";" & hostname_IP_value)
            objTextFile.Close
            document.getElementById("hostname").value=hostname
        Exit Sub    
    End If
    Loop
```

Even when inputting identical hostname values the script doesn't capture the condition to display the

```
MsgBox "found hostname = " & hostname & " in the savedhosts.txt file"
```

Instead it just appends it to the txt file, resulting in 2 text names with different values, which is not desirable!

Answer (score 0):

I would change your `Exit Sub` statements to `Exit Do`. If that doesn't fix it, then specify VBTextCompare in the InStr function (eg, `InStr(myLine, hostname, 1)`). If that still doesn't fix it, check your data because it may not be in the format you believe its in. You may have to `Escape(myLine)` (and/or `hostname` since you don't mention how that variable gets set) to ensure you're comparing apples to apples.

Comment: That doesn't work. The data is a simple text file that works fine when called throughout the script. I also make sure I close the file correctly, houskeeping rules.